# BX Slider - div class wrapper error

Tags: jquery, slider, jquery-ui-slider, bxslider

I'm working with bxslider for the first time, not very well versed in javascript at all, but I've been piecing some items together as I go. I had the slider setup perfectly and when I went to upload to server, I replaced one of my jquery files. Now it won't load right and I can't figure out why.

you can see on this link
http://www.blackheartmx.com/index.html

I don't know if its a conflicting CSS file or an error in the jquery file but I'm stumped.
I had the slider flawlessly integrated, so it would look like one of the ordering pages.

http://www.blackheartmx.com/crf-calamity.html (for example the image positioning without bx slider).

I would sincerely appreciate some help!

Comment: This might have something to do with it: http://www.blackheartmx.com/js/jquery.bxslider.css

Comment: I've went through that CSS file over and over, I can't see where it might be causing the "bx-slider" to be so small now?